# Store ABI Value in var

Tags: web3js, javascript, etherscan, jquery

I've finally managed to get my web3.js to work.. I did this only for the purpose to display one specific value on my website.. I'm not so good with jquery and hope you guys can help me out.

This is the Direct link to the ABI Value

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=0xD2354AcF1a2f06D69D8BC2e2048AaBD404445DF6&data=0xd679677a&tag=latest

Contract Link ( https://etherscan.io/address/0xd2354acf1a2f06d69d8bc2e2048aabd404445df6#readContract )

Line ( 28. currentTier )

It is in HexDec. and I need to output it in Decimal. I quess I will need to store the Value in a Var and output it in html.. but kinda lost how to exactly do it.

Hope you can help me out. Thank you very much

Comment: Please share your code. If you call `currentTier()` using web3.js, you should get back a `BigNumber` (or `BN`, if using the 1.0 beta) instance, and you can just call `.toString()` or `.toNumber()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the `currentTier` function.  Your callback will be invoked with an error (if there is one) and a result, which is a `BigNumber` instance. Call `.toString()` on it to convert the value to a base-10 string. The below code assumes web3.js 0.2x.x. If you're using the 1.0 beta, the syntax is a little different:

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"currentTier","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint16"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]).at('0xd2354acf1a2f06d69d8bc2e2048aabd404445df6');
contract.currentTier(function (err, result) { console.log(result.toString()); });
// output: 351
```

You mentioned jQuery. To display the value in your HTML, you can do something like `$('#myelement').text(result.toString())` instead.